# Check if Char Array contains special sequence without using string library on Unix in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, unix, sequence

Let‘s assume we have a char array and a sequence. Next we would like to check if the char array contains the special sequence `WITHOUT <string.h> LIBRARY`: if yes -> return true; if no -> return false.

```
bool contains(char *Array, char *Sequence) {
     // CONTAINS - Function
     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Array); i++) {
         for (int s = 0; s < sizeof(Sequence); s++) {
             if (Array[i] == Sequence[i]) {
            
                 // How to check if Sequence is contained ?  
             }
         }
     }
    return false;
}
// in Main Function
char *Arr = "ABCDEFG";
char *Seq = "AB";
bool contained = contains(Arr, Seq);
if (contained) {
    printf("Contained\n");
} else {
    printf("Not Contained\n"); 
}
```

Any ideas, suggestions, websites ... ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards, from ∆

Comment: What is `bools`?

Comment: `sizeof(Array)` and `sizeof(Sequences)` are not the length of strings but sizes of the pointers.

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh thanks, what to use then ?

Comment: @MikeCAT #bools -> Writing Error, I apologize ;(

Comment: By using `strlen()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is expected that you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, which avoids those typo mistakes which make readers wonder what *else* isn't 'real code'. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WeatherVane By implementing function like `strlen()` and using that, because `string.h` cannot be used here.

Comment: @MikeCAT of course, no libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is the naive search function:

```
for (i = 0; i < lenS1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lenS2; j++) {
        if (arr[i] != seq[j]) {
            break; // seq is not present in arr at position i!
        }
    }
    if (j == lenS2) {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Note that **you cannot use sizeof** because the value you seek is not known at run time. Sizeof will return the pointer size, so almost certainly always four or eight whatever the strings you use. You need to explicitly calculate the string lengths, which in C is done by knowing that the last character of the string is a zero:

```
lenS1 = 0;
while (string1[lenS1]) lenS1++;
lenS2 = 0;
while (string2[lenS2]) lenS2++;
```

An obvious and easy improvement is to limit i between 0 and lenS1 - lenS2, and if lenS1 < lenS2, immediately return false. Obviously if you haven't found "HELLO" in "WELCOME" by the time you've gotten to the 'L', there's no chance of five-character HELLO being ever contained in the four-character remainder COME:

```
if (lenS1 < lenS2) {
    return false; // You will never find "PEACE" in "WAR".
}
lenS1minuslenS2 = lenS1 - lenS2;

for (i = 0; i < lenS1minuslenS2; i++)
```

Further improvements **depend on your use case**.

Looking for the same sequence among lots of arrays, looking for different sequences always in the same array, looking for lots of different sequences in lots of different arrays - all call for different optimizations.

The length and distribution of characters within both array and sequence also matter a lot, because if you know that there only are (say) three E's in a long string and you know where they are, and you need to search for HELLO, there's only three places where HELLO might fit. So you needn't scan the whole "WE WISH YOU A MERRY CHRISTMAS, WE WISH YOU A MERRY CHRISTMAS AND A HAPPY NEW YEAR" string. Actually you may notice there are no L's in the array and immediately return false.

A balanced option for an average use case (it *does* have pathological cases) might be supplied by the [Boyer-Moore string matching algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) (C source and explanation supplied at the link). This has a setup cost, so if you need to look for different *short strings* within *very large texts*, it is not a good choice (there is a parallel-search version which is good for some of those cases).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient algorithm but I do not want to change your code too much.

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;
    while(*end++);

    return end - str - 1;
}

bool contains(char *Array, char *Sequence) {
     // CONTAINS - Function
     bool result = false;
     size_t s, i;

     size_t arrayLen = mystrlen(Array);
     size_t sequenceLen = mystrlen(Sequence);

    if(sequenceLen <= arrayLen)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
            for (s = 0; s < sequenceLen; s++) 
            {
                if (Array[i + s] != Sequence[s]) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(s == sequenceLen) 
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *Arr = "ABCDEFG";
    char *Seq = "AB";
    bool contained = contains(Arr, Seq);
    if (contained) 
    {
        printf("Contained\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("Not Contained\n"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is `strstr`

```
const char* strstrn(const char* orig, const char* pat, int n)
{
    const char* it = orig;
    do
    {
        const char* tmp = it;
        const char* tmp2 = pat;
        if (*tmp == *tmp2) {
            while (*tmp == *tmp2 && *tmp != '\0') {
                tmp++;
                tmp2++;
            }
            if (n-- == 0)
                return it;
        }
        tmp = it;
        tmp2 = pat;
    } while (*it++ != '\0');
    return  NULL;
}
```

The above returns `n` matches of substring in a string.

Comment: It returns a pointer to the matched n occurrence in a string and returns a pointer to the match, if you need a `bool` for match or not, might check for `NULL`, just a suggestion.

Comment: @IlianZaprynaow I either need to a bool or number of occurrence, that shouldn’t be to difficult